# Bipolar junction transistor circuit added after common source amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, bjt, common-source

I am studying for a class at university and our teacher gave us this circuit diagram and asked us to calculate the amplification, the DC version of the circuit and the small signal model for it.

[image]

I have seen the common source amplifier before but I don't know what the second transistor is doing there.

Comment: Well, the usual BJT circuits are common emitter, common collector, and common base -- which of those do you think the BJT circuit would be, and why?

Comment: Well going by the name it could be a common collector, because R4 and R5 are connected together and to the collector?

Comment: Look at which terminal of the BJT the output is taken from, that should give you a clue about which terminal is "common".

Comment: So still a collector? the ouput is taken from there

Comment: The term 'common' in transistor circuits refers to which terminal is common to both the input and output circuits. If you look at the input and output signal paths for a transistor one terminal will be in both paths.